# Run-time error 13 on VBA using ElseIf / If / Else

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a code which is supposed to call on other macros and apply depending on the sheet name:
I get the error

> Run-time error '13': type mismatch

on line `If sht.Name = "NB12" Or "NB15" Then` which I assume will continue further down my code. What have I done wrong?

```
Sub Specify_test2()


    Dim Fun As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        'Select Case sht.Name
            If sht.Name = "NB12" Or "NB15" Then
                Call limits_Alluvium
            ElseIf sht.Name = "NB24" Then
                Call limits_BOCOBOML_GFA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "NB16" Or "NB17" Or "NB19" Or "NB20" Or "Bore 31" Then
                Call limits_BOCOBOML_MIA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 47" Or "Bore 48" Then
                Call limits_FracturedRock_GFA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 4" Or "Bore 4a" Or "Bore 40" Then
                Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 30" Then
                Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East
            Else
                Call limits_Monitoring_bores
End If
        'End Select
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `sht.Name = "NB12" Or sht.Name = "NB15"`

Comment: Using `Select Case` may be more appropriate for this kind of thing, not sure why you replaced it with a bunch of `ElseIf`s. You are also missing the `End if`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I was using ```Select Case``` but was having issues so I thought I would try another method

Comment: You can also remove the `Call` line. This has been deprecated.Naming the macro you want to call is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you use `Or` the code isn't then referencing the first condition you set, so you have to specify the Sheet again. i.e.

```
If sht.Name = "NB12" Or sht.Name = "NB15" Then
```

instead of

```
If sht.Name = "NB12" Or "NB15" Then
```

The same applies to every line where you're checking for more than one condition